# Collection filter AND condition

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

we use the wrapper for sql queries instead of the raw ones.

```
I have a collection, which has two fields A and B. 
I want to query when (A = red AND B = square) OR (A = blue AND  = circle)
```

When we try to use **`addAttributeToFilter`**, I don't see any option to handle such cases.

So, is there any way I can fetch data in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```php
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where(
        new \Zend_Db_Expr("(A = 'red' AND B = 'square') OR (A = 'blue' AND B = 'circle')")
    );
```

Comment: Will this work : 
`Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()->getSelect()
                    ->where(
                        new \Zend_Db_Expr("(state = 'complete') OR (state = 'canceled')")
                    );`

Answer (score 0):

Or condition should work like this

```php
// Or
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'status',
        'eq'      => 'complete',
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'status',
        'eq'        => 'canceled',
    ),
));
```